# Varnish: How often is DNS name lookup done when specified in ACL?

Tags: domain-name-system, varnish

I specified a dyndns domain name in a ACL of Varnish, so only IPs of this domain name should be allowed.

This is working fine until my IP changed. Then I get a forbidden error until I restart varnish.

How often does varnish refresh the DNS lookup?

I know it might be slow to do such lookups, but this is anyways not a production site.

Comment: Seems impossible? http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/varnish/misc/22159

Answer (score 0):

With few lines of scripting you will be able to do that.

You need to setup a shell script which its purpose will be to periodically `dig +short` your domain name and if IP has changed, will reload varnish.

Comment: Not necessary. A varnish reload is enough. On parsing the config, varnish always does a lookup. Problem: Varnish reload looses the cache.

Comment: I'm talking about "reload" not "restart". You will lose the cache only when restarting.

Answer (score 0):

On parsing the config, varnish always does a lookup. Problem: Varnish reload looses the cache.

Solution: Using the varnish console load the new config under a different name, remove the old one.